# Realizing the Berkovich affine line as a union of Berkovich spectrums

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, spectra, geometric-functional-analysis

I am trying to understand what is the relation of the affine Berkovich space to the Berkovich space on an appropriate polynomial ring. A more exact version of the question is as follows:

Let $(K,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ be a complete valued field. The affine Berkovich space is defined as:

$ A_K^{n, \text{an}}:=
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    &  \vert f+g\vert_x \leq \vert f\vert_x +\vert g\vert_x  \\
    \vert \cdot \vert _x:K[x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow [0,\infty) \quad \Bigg \vert  & \vert f\cdot g\vert_x= \vert f\vert_x \cdot \vert g\vert_x \\
     &  \vert a\vert_x= \Vert a\Vert \; \text{for all } \; a\in K
  \end{Bmatrix}  $

i.e, non-trivial multiplicative semi-norms on $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ extending $\Vert \cdot \Vert$. Given a Banach ring $(A,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$, it's Berkovich  spectrum is:

$ \mathcal{M}(A):= \begin{Bmatrix}
   \text{multiplicative bounded seminorms}  \\
   \vert \cdot \vert : A \rightarrow [0,\infty) 
  \end{Bmatrix}  $

They both have the weakest topology induced by evaluations.

I have been trying to understand what is the relation between $A_K^{n, \text{an}}$ and a Berkovich spectrum of $K[x_1,...,x_n]$. They would coincide were it not for the extra assumption of boundedness. I saw somewhere that the Berkovich affine space is not a Berkovich spectrum, but instead an increasing union of Berkovich spectrums of power rings.

I have not found thus far how these spectrums are defined, and would appreciate anyone explaining, or directing to a reference where it is indeed written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me see if I can help a bit; please let me know if you need more clarification. First of all, I don't know of many basic references on Berkovich spaces. One you might consider is the first two chapters in [Baker–Rumely](https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/159) (which works over an algebraically closed field). For another reference, you might find [this set of notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~takumim/Berkovich.pdf) (especially §5) and the citations therein helpful.

To make this discussion a bit simpler, we will work over a complete non-Archimedean valued field $(K,\lvert\cdot\rvert)$, and only consider the case when $n = 1$.

Let's first recall that Berkovich's notion of a spectrum $\mathcal{M}(A)$ needs $A$ to be a Banach ring. To make sense of the Berkovich spectrum of $K[x]$, then, one would want to put a norm on this ring that makes it complete. The usual choice (the "Gauss norm")
$$\biggl\lVert \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i \biggr\rVert = \max_i \lvert a_i \rvert$$
would make it so that the polynomial ring is not complete unless the field $K$ is trivially valued. In general, we therefore consider the Banach ring (the "Tate algebra")
$$K\{x\} := \biggl\{ f = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i \biggm\vert a_i \in K,\ \lim_{i \to \infty} \lvert a_i \rvert = 0 \biggr\}$$
which can be thought of as the "ring of convergent power series on the closed disc of radius $1$." Note that in the trivially valued case, this ring is just the usual polynomial ring.

Now borrowing the usual intuition from algebraic geometry, the ring $A$ that we take the spectrum of should consist of all regular functions on the space $\mathcal{M}(A)$. In this case, $\mathcal{M}(K\{x\})$ should therefore be thought of as a closed disc of radius $1$; after all, if you take an element of $K\{x\}$ and plug an element of $K$ with norm $>1$, then the power series can diverge!

To get closed discs with larger radii, then, Berkovich changes the norm and considers the ring
$$K\{r^{-1}x\} := \biggl\{ f = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i \biggm\vert a_i \in K,\ \lim_{i \to \infty} \lvert a_i \rvert r^i = 0 \biggr\}$$
for each $r > 0$, which now can be thought of as the "ring of convergent power series on the closed disc of radius $r$." The closed disc of radius $r$ is
$$E(r) := \mathcal{M}(K\{r^{-1}x\}),$$
and we can define the affine line as
$$\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathrm{Berk}} := \bigcup_{r > 0} E(r).$$

Comment: Also, when OP says the ``Berkovich spectrum of $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$'', this is not well-defined-you need to equip the polynomial ring with this norm. One choice of norm is a Gauss norm $| \cdot |_{\mathbf{r}}$ associated to the tuple $\mathbf{r} = (r_1,\ldots,r_n)$. In this case, the Berkovich spectrum of $(K[x_1,\ldots,x_n], | \cdot |_{\mathbf{r}})$ is the spectrum of its completion (i.e, the Tate algebra $K \{ r^{-1} x \}$ as above), giving the closed disc, as in Takumi's answer. Taking the union over all possible choices of norms on $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ gives $\mathbf{A}^n_{\mathrm{Berk}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the Baker Rumley refrence.